# Referencing an arn declared in a module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a folder `/modules/firehose` where i've declared a file as such:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "purchase_logs_firehose_stream" {
  name        = var.firehose_stream_name
  destination = "extended_s3"
  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn        = var.firehose_role_arn
    buffer_interval = 60
    buffer_size     = 64
    bucket_arn      = var.destination_bucket_arn
  }
}
variable "firehose_stream_name" {
  description = "name of your stream"
}

variable "firehose_role_arn" {
}

variable "destination_bucket_arn" {

}
```

I then import the module in the root directory as such:

```
module "purchase_logs_firehose_prod" {
  source                 = "./modules/firehose"
  firehose_stream_name   = "purchase_logs_firehose_prod"
  firehose_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.purchase_logs_firehose_role.arn
  destination_bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.purchase_logs_destination_prod.arn
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "purchase_logs_destination_prod" {
  bucket = "purchase-logs-prod-dump"
}
```

[According to the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream#arn) there is an attribute `arn` which i can reference afterwards. However when i try to reference it else where as `module.purchase_logs_firehose_prod.arn` i get an error

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on iam.tf line 83, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy":
│   83:             ${module.purchase_logs_firehose_prod.arn}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.purchase_logs_firehose_prod is a object
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

I'm really not sure what the source of the error is. If I even check the state file (after removing the code causing the error and running `terraform apply`, i see an `arn` attribute for the resource in question). Any input appreciated!

Here is the file `iam.tf` where i try to reference it

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name        = "ec2-policy"


  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
            "*"
        ],
        "Resource":[
            "${module.purchase_logs_firehose_prod.arn}" 
        ]
      }
  ]
}
EOF

}
```

Comment: You haven't actually given the file where the error is happening. It is in the `iam.tf` file on line 83, so please add the relevant code block to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you have to define an output at the module level:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "purchase_logs_firehose_stream" {
  name        = var.firehose_stream_name
  destination = "extended_s3"
  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn        = var.firehose_role_arn
    buffer_interval = 60
    buffer_size     = 64
    bucket_arn      = var.destination_bucket_arn
  }
}
variable "firehose_stream_name" {
  description = "name of your stream"
}

variable "firehose_role_arn" {
}

variable "destination_bucket_arn" {

}

output "firehose_prod_arn" {
  description = "Kinesis Firehose ARN."
  value       = aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.purchase_logs_firehose_stream.arn
}
```

Then, you can reference it in the `iam.tf` file like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name        = "ec2-policy"


  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
            "*"
        ],
        "Resource":[
            module.purchase_logs_firehose_prod.firehose_prod_arn
        ]
      }
  ]
}
EOF

}
```

More information about using outputs can be found in [the docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs), while the exact explanation on how referencing the module outputs works is a [subsection](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs#accessing-child-module-outputs).

Comment: that did it! do you have a link to the docs that explain how it works?

Comment: Updated the answer with references.

Comment: wish i could buy you a coffee or something haha

Comment: Haha, just keep spreading the knowledge further!